# Gembox spreadsheet. is there a way to make it fit to one page when saving to pdf

Tags: gembox-spreadsheet

Im trying to find a way to convert xls files to pdf, and gembox spreadsheet is great for this. But i need to be able to make it fit to one page as you can when printing to pdf via excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying `FitWorksheetWidthToPages` and `FitWorksheetHeightToPages` properties.
For example like the following:

```cs
ExcelFile workbook = ExcelFile.Load("Sample.xls");
ExcelWorksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet;

worksheet.PrintOptions.FitWorksheetWidthToPages = 1;
worksheet.PrintOptions.FitWorksheetHeightToPages = 1;

workbook.Save("Sample.pdf");
```

I hope this helps.